# using same axis labels as listed in the data file

Tags: label, gnuplot, axis

i have a simple dat file with 36 values in a range from 0 to 100.
Is it possible to use this 36 values as y-lables instead of the automatically generated labels? This 36 y-values are sorted from 0 to 100, but have a irregular gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `yticlabel` function:

```
plot 'file.txt' using 1:2:yticlabel(2)
```